# Count number of days between given two dates grouped by month in a table

Tags: r

I have a set of start and end dates. I have to calculate the number of days month wise excluding weekends and national holidays. The output data appears here:

[image]

The code is getting too complicated and not giving proper results.

The code I tried is:

```
sd ="24-Jan-18"
ed ="4-Mar-18"
sd_m <- ymd(strptime(as.character(sd), format = "%d-%b-%y"))
ed_m <- ymd(strptime(as.character(ed), format = "%d-%b-%y"))
s_m <- format(sd_m, "%b-%Y")
  e_m <-  format(ed_m, "%b-%Y")
  no_months<- (year(ed_m) - year(sd_m)) * 12 + month(ed_m) - month(sd_m) +1
  i = 0
  day_count = as.vector(0)
  e_mon = as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(sd_m),as.yearmon(ed_m),1/12),frac = 1)
  s_mon =   as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(sd_m),as.yearmon(ed_m),1/12),frac = 0)
  day_count[1]= = sum(!weekdays(seq(sd_m ,e_mon[1], "days")) %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday')) -holiday
  i=2
  for (i in 1:(no_months-1)){
   day_count[i]= sum(!weekdays(seq(s_mon[i], e_mon[i], "days")) %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday')) -holiday } 
  day_count[no_months] = sum(!weekdays(seq(s_mon[no_months],ed_m, "days")) %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday')) -holiday
```

And to count holidays I was thinking of writing a for loop which doesn't help.
`hol =c("2018-01-26" "2018-05-01" "2018-08-15" "2018-09-13" "2018-10-02" "2018-12-25")`

I tried using bizdays
`create.calendar(name ='my_cal', holidays = hol1,weekdays = c('Saturday', 'Sunday'))`

But it gives an error:

```
bizdays(sd_m,e_mon[1],my_cal)
Error in check_calendar(cal) : object 'my_cal' not found
```

Please help build!!

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse approach, using some lubridate functions

```
sd ="2018-01-24"
ed ="2018-03-04"

#create a data.frame with all days from startdata (sd) to end date (ed)
df <- data.frame( dates = seq( as.Date(sd), as.Date(ed), by = "days"))

#create the vector with Holiday-dates
holidays_v <- as.Date( c("2018-01-26", "2018-05-01", "2018-08-15", "2018-09-13", "2018-10-02", "2018-12-25") )

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  #filter out all days that are Sundays (wday == 1), or Saturdays (wday == 7), of within the vector with Holidays
  filter( !lubridate::wday( dates ) %in% c(1,7) & !dates %in% holidays_v ) %>%
  #create period to summarise by (here: year-month)
  mutate( period = paste( lubridate::year(dates), formatC(lubridate::month(dates), width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0"), sep = "-") ) %>%
  # group by period
  group_by( period ) %>%
  #... and summarise
  summarise( number = n() )

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   period  number
#   <chr>    <int>
# 1 2018-01      5
# 2 2018-02     20
# 3 2018-03      2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I still have a doubt. The value for 2018-01 should be 5 . Because 27-01-2018 and 28-01-2018 is weekend and as per my holiday list 26-01-2018 is a holiday. So total working days are 5. I dont know why <!dates %in% holidays_v > this filter is not working   `> df$dates[3]
[1] "2018-01-26"
> holidays_v[1]
[1] "2018-01-26"
> df$dates[3] == holidays_v[1]
[1] TRUE
> df$dates %in% holidays_v   (gives all false values)`

Comment: @user2601604 I edited my answer.. fixed now, the outcome is as in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base solution.  Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end `toLong` creates a data frame `d` with one row per date and removes the weekends and holidays from it.  Then it aggregates that by year and month.  That is applied to each row of the input giving a list `L` of data frames which are `rbind`-ed together.  Finally that is converted to wide form.  The last line of code can be omitted if column names of the form yyyy-mm are ok.

```
toLong <- function(row, sd, ed, hol) {
  s <- seq(sd, ed, "day")
  d <- data.frame(row, s, ym = format(s, "%Y-%m"))
  d <- subset(d, ! weekdays(s) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"))
  d <- subset(d, ! s %in% hol)
  data.frame(row, sd, ed, aggregate(s ~ ym, d, FUN = length))
}

L <- Map(toLong, 1:nrow(DF), DF$sd, DF$ed, MoreArgs = list(hol = hol))
DF2 <- do.call("rbind", L)
xt <- xtabs(s ~ row + ym, DF2)
DF3 <- cbind(DF, as.data.frame.matrix(xt))
names(DF3)[-(1:2)] <- format(as.Date(paste0(names(DF3)[-(1:2)], "-01")), "%b %Y")
```

giving:

```
> DF3
          sd         ed Oct 2018 Nov 2018 Jan 2018 Feb 2018 Mar 2018
1 2018-10-01 2018-11-01       23        1        0        0        0
2 2018-01-24 2018-03-04        0        0        6       20        2
```

### Note

The input in reproducible from is:

```
DF <-
  structure(list(sd = structure(c(17805, 17555), class = "Date"), 
    ed = structure(c(17836, 17594), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
  -2L), class = "data.frame")

hol <- as.Date(c("2018-01-26", "2018-05-01", "2018-08-15", "2018-09-13", 
  "2018-10-02", "2018-12-25"))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But in your case as well. It is not subtracting the hoilday day. It should be 5 days for the month of january

Comment: OK. Have added holidays.